# Django filter is not working correctly with boolean field

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have a very simple query to filter but really unable to understand why it is giving me wrong result.

This is my code -

```
    for s in sqs:
        print(s.is_draft)
    sqs = sqs.filter(is_draft=False)
    print('----------------------')
    for s in sqs:
        print(s,s.is_draft)
```

What I am getting is -

```
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='82')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='87')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='94')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='99')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='101')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='106')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='118')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='84')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='91')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='96')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='103')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='108')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='110')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='115')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='85')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='92')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='97')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='104')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='111')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='83')> True
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='95')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='102')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='107')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='119')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='93')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='98')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='100')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='105')> False
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='112')> False
----------------------
<SearchResult: products.productcreatemodel (pk='83')> True
```

It should return me the queryset of those which are having `is_draft=False` but in this you can clearly see it return me the queryset with objects having `is_draft=True`

Now the magic is when I change the code to `sqs = sqs.filter(is_draft=True)` again the result is same !!

Its really understandable.

Comment: To filter objects: `my_object =MyObject.objects.filter(is_draft=False) `
`for s in sqs:
        print(s.is_draft)`

Comment: @CarlosHerrera actually I am using haystack for search this is not filtering from models but from `<class 'haystack.query.SearchQuerySet'>`  see this - https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchqueryset_api.html#searchqueryset